# Turn off bluetooth on startup

Tags: bluetooth, startup

I'm looking for a way to have bluetooth turned off every time I start my computer, but without loosing ability to turn it on again using only switch in wingpanel.

I've seen many answers to similar questions recommending adding `rfkill block bluetooth` to `/etc/rc.local` but then I can't turn it on using switch, I have to manually unblock it.

A few answers said to change `InitiallyPowered` option in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` but I don't have that option in that file, and adding it manually didn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to [Porshe Man's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/14591/13430) I have noticed interesting thing. `dconf` option named `bluetooth-enabled` stores the current value of bluetooth switch just for the purpose of setting that state at the next start, so there's no need to edit `dconf`, just using the toggle will do exactly the same thing.

However it doesn't work (at least for me) when I use the `restart` option. When I reboot my computer by shutting it down and then turning it on again it works just fine. This is the reason I thought I need some special solution - when I wanted to see if bluetooth state is remembered I used `restart` option.

It looks like it's not a big problem, I will just not use `restart` option but I guess this behavior is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Because of where I use my laptop at times, I also needed to have the machine boot with Bluetooth off. Here is how I did it:

1. I installed dconf-editor. This can be done via the AppCenter or at a command line by typing `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` then entering your password.
2. Open dconf-editor from the app menu.
3. Navigate to org-> pantheon-> desktop-> wingpanel-> indicators-> bluetooth

Once you're there, you should see only one listing named "bluetooth-enabled" with a check mark in the value field. Simply un-check the box then close dconf-editor and reboot. After a reboot, you should see that the Bluetooth Icon is still on the panel but it is not enabled by default. You can click on the icon and enable when it's needed.

Hope this helps!

P.S.-**Be very careful using dconf-editor** as it does allow a user to make a huge number of changes and some changes can have a negative consequence in that you can do serious damage to your system. I learned that the hard way some years ago!