# How can I turn off bluetooth while being able to turn it on from the indicator later?

Tags: wingpanel, bluetooth

When I switch bluetooth off, bluetoothctl says that it's powered off but powertop says that btusb is consuming 2.5W of power, so it isn't off..

If I execute `rfkill block bluetooth` it does power it off, but I need to execute `rfkill unblock bluetooth` when I want to use bluetooth again. Is there any other way to do what I want without using the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. The solution for me was that I actually have a "soft" hardware key for bluetooth on my F10 key. If I have the bluetooth turned on there then btusb shows up at 100% in powertop regardless of software setting. Using the function key will turn it on and off correctly.

Comment: I don't have such key. I do have one to switch off wireless but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this semi fixed on my HP 840 G2.  I downloaded dconf editor and changed the setting there.  It isn't a full fix.  While it defaults it on a reboot to off, if the laptop locks and I unlock, its back on.  I have got into the custom of shutting down after use so this pretty much solves it for me.  Hoping to get some time to look into the issue with the locking/unlocking later in the week.

haven't looked into whether or not this kills power but it does allow control via the desktop indicator.

I installed dconf editor through terminal, the "how to" I followed mentioned that it can be done through the app store as well but i didn't verify this.

to install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Here is the link to the answer this was derived from.

elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14587/…

Last, the path listed in the how to didn't follow the same for me.  I had to go:

io/elementary/desktop/wingpanel/bluetooth

Once there I was able to set the default setting to off.  as stated before it works with reboots, but not for timeout/lock.

Comment: I invite you to write in detail what you did for future reference

Comment: I installed dconf editor through terminal, the how to I followed also mentioned that it can be installed through the app center.  for installing via terminal,

Comment: I installed dconf editor through terminal, the how to I followed also mentioned that it can be installed through the app center.  for installing via terminal, "sudo apt-get install dconf-editor"  here is the link to the question and how to.  "https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14587/turn-off-bluetooth-on-startup?rq=1"  for me, the path didn't work to the setting.  i had to go io/elementary/desktop/wingpanel/bluetooth

Comment: edit your answer, not comment